# Ajax pagination with the Kaminari gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, jquery-pagination

After a [recent railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari) I'm using the [kaminari gem](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) in my [website](http://alivefrommaryhill.net) and I want to do ajax pagination

The kaminari docs say: `the helper supports Rails 3 unobtrusive Ajax.`

Does anyone have any hints or tutorials on how to do this? I'm using jquery, rails 3 etc. I guess I need something in my application.js file that listens to the buttons in the pagination nav

If anyone needs code I will post it

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Thank you for using Kaminari.

I just created a brief sample project using Kaminari and jQuery, as I believe this is the best way to show you the actual code. git log tells you more than words!

So, could you take a look at the commits here on "ajax" branch?  https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_example/commits/ajax

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is an old old example and does not seem to be working with Rails 3. I do get the call to the server however my view is not updating? Is there anyway someone could assist further?

Comment: This assumes you have just a restful index action and nothing else, I am investigating other options.

Answer (score 0):

I did it according to the following simple article and everything works pretty well

[Ajax pagination with kaminari](http://www.joshondevelopment.com/post/3752155526/ajax-pagination-with-kaminari)

Comment: Tried following the same article but no luck.