# Kaminari paginate but re-submit form parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I am using the [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem to paginate my products list.

This search feature currently works with AJAX and has a top-bar filter style search:

[image]

This implies that a few parameters are passed from this search bar to the controller where they are processed to filter the results.

The kaminari `paginate` helper, however has its own links and it redirects to the controller action with only the `:page` parameter, and thus the rest of my search filters are ignored. So when I click on the page 2  or Next link, the products are no longer filtered and it shows page 2 of *all products*.

I need the search parameters to be sent every time a pagination link is clicked. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post please. It's answered by the maker of awesome Kaminari gem.

[Ajax pagination with the Kaminari gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158532/ajax-pagination-with-the-kaminari-gem)

I am not sure if you are using a gem for search functionality. If you are, this post might be helpful:

http://techbrownbags.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/rails-ajax-search-sort-paginate-with-ransack-kaminari/